# How do I force Cromwell / WDL to put input files in the same directory?

Tags: wdl

I have a cromwell task that, among other variables, takes these three variables:

```
   File Ref             # Reference genome fasta
   File RefFai          # Reference Genome index
   File RefDict         # Reference Dictionary
```

While all three files make it into the task's "inputs" directory, they end up in different sub-directories of inputs:

```
ME $ find inputs
inputs

inputs/-181926642
inputs/-181926642/Sample.vcf.bgz.tbi
inputs/-181926642/Sample.vcf.bgz
inputs/-1548908437
inputs/-1548908437/GCA_000001405.15_GRCh38_no_alt_short_headers_nonACTG_to_N.dict
inputs/44588251
inputs/44588251/GCA_000001405.15_GRCh38_no_alt_short_headers_nonACTG_to_N.fa
inputs/44588251/GCA_000001405.15_GRCh38_no_alt_short_headers_nonACTG_to_N.fa.fai
```

Which means that when I call GATK and pass it the path to the .fa file, it gets rather cranky that the .dict file isn't in the same directory.

How do I force cromwell to put all three files in the same directory?

Comment: We did have a similar problem and there is a solution to it... however, I have hard time recalling it, sinc eit was a while ago (and we abandoned WDL). Perhaps you could paste the code for the task, which would make it easier to see, if anything is missing.

Comment: @Vadim the code does not reference RefFai or RefDict, only Ref.

Comment: I am talking about the wdl code: one must pass all the files explicitly to the task, even if they do not appear in the command line. Every task is run from a separate folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hacktastic fix for this is to use basename to get the name of each file, then do

```
refName=`basename "${Ref}"`
ln -s "${Ref}" "$refName"
```

for each file.  This puts aliases to each file in the executions dir, and then I pass "refName" to GATK rather than "${Ref}".

Not a good solution, but a solution

Answer (score 1):

as for wdl version 1.0 (other versions untested)

you can pack your reference and related files into a struct:

```
struct Reference {
    File fasta
    File dict
    File fai
}
```

You will pass the `Reference` to your tasks instead of `File`.
Inside your workflow/config define:

```
Ref example = {
    "fasta" : "reference.fasta",
    "fai" : "reference.fasta.fai",
    "dict" : "reference.dict"
}
```

Inside the task you just use the file want use by `example.fasta`.